# How to replace array value defined as variable passed in another file?

Tags: php, arrays, parameter-passing

I'm working on some function that can accept argument as any array. Some value in this array is defined as variable. This function is class method defined in another file. Is there any way to replace that variable in array by variable defined in method?

The main goal is to have ability to pass `$args` array with different structure, but there always be a variable `$filter_value` as value of one array key.

I want to tell method in some way to replace that vaiable with dynamic value that will be passed as `$_GET` parametr.

So now method accept all args, create array from it, push in global property as array element. And then runing `run()` method tring to merge two arrays, one of them is passed to method, and there should be placed value insted of `$filter_value` variable

test.php

```
$authors_arr = array(
    '5' => 'author_name',
    '7' => 'author_name2',
);
$args = array('author'=>$filter_value);

$dynamic_admin = new DynamicAdmin();
$dynamic_admin->addFilter( 'post', 'author', __('All authors','fn'), $authors_arr, $args);
$dynamic_admin->run();
```

class.php

```
class DynamicAdmin{
   private $filter_fn = array();
   public function addFilter($post_type, $meta_key, $label, $value_list, $args){
       $args_arr = compact('post_type', 'meta_key', 'label', 'value_list','args');
       $this->filter_fn[] = $args_arr;
   }
   public function run(){
      foreach ($this->filter_fn as $filter){
         $filter_value = $_GET[$filter['meta_key']];
         $query->query_vars = array_merge($query->query_vars, $filter['args']);
      }
   }
};
```

For example in current case `$filter['meta_key'] = 'author'`, in my URL there `?auhor=5` and after `run()` method i want to get `$query->query_vars` looks like:

```
Array(
  ...,
  'author' => 5,
  ...,
)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually try to do. Your phrasing is somewhat difficult to follow. Could you please add some demonstration of input and expected output values to your example?

Comment: add more info, hope now its more clear :)

Comment: I think there is a miss conception here... Once your array is defined, there is no trace of a variable in it any more. It only contains values.

Comment: i have add example in the end of question, can you please check it again?

Comment: I _think_ I know where you want to go to, but you need to use another approach: You can create a "closure" instead of that initial array. Such closure is an anonymous function. Implement it such that it returns an array when executed, an array with a value it receives as argument placed as value in the array at the location of that "variable inside the array". Such closure can be saved inside a variable itself, so it can be handled over to your object and stored internally. Now at runtime to can execute that closed and hand over any value you want and have at that time.

Comment: so do you mean something like that?
`$args = function($value){return array('author'=>$value);};`

Comment: Yep, right direction. This allows to define the array early but "finalize" it later, kind of...

Comment: but im not sure how to store in object as before, will it wok with `compact()`?

Comment: Sure, you can do that, why not? From that functions point of view the closure is nothing but a variable value again...

Comment: ok, i get it, thank you so much!

Comment: Of course that does not actually have to be a closure, you could instead also use some object for that. You define a class, something like `class arrayWithValueNotYetFinalized` which gets defines a `finalize($value)` function that does exactly what we discussed with the closure example. A question of personal preference.

Comment: @arkascha Are you able to post some sort of meaningful answer that Alexey can mark as accepted?  This question appear unresolved / abandoned.

Comment: Can this question be resolved with a meaningful answer instead of a few upvoted comments?  If there is value in this question, the answer is hidden deeply in comments and that is not how SO is meant to work.  If no meaningful/helpful answer can be devised, that usually indicates that this question has low or no value and should be deleted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @arkascha i've figureed out how to make it possible. Pass array as anonymous function:

```
$args = function ($value) {
    return array('author'=>$value);
}
```

pass it as usual

```
$dynamic_admin->addFilter( 'post', 'author', __('All authors','fn'), $authors_arr, $args);
```

and call will be

```
class DynamicAdmin{
   private $filter_fn = array();
   public function addFilter($post_type, $meta_key, $label, $value_list, $args){
       $args_arr = compact('post_type', 'meta_key', 'label', 'value_list','args');
       $this->filter_fn[] = $args_arr;
   }
   public function run(){
      foreach ($this->filter_fn as $filter){
         $filter_value = $_GET[$filter['meta_key']];
         $query->query_vars = array_merge($query->query_vars, $filter['args']( $filter_value ));
      }
   }
};
```